# Android - Webview HTML code extraction doesn't work (Javascript)

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, webview

I'm coding an app which:
- load a URL in a Webview;
- extract the HTML thorugh a javascript code;
- show the extracted HTML code in the LOG.

As i need to load the page without Javascript enabled (to avoid some behaviors of the page), i tried the code below where:
- i load the page in the webview with the Javascript disabled;
- when the page is loaded, i enable the Javascript;
- then, the app execute the Javascript required to extract the HTML code.

Unfortunately, when the code is executed in debug mode on Android 4.0.4, it gives an error:

```
01-22 22:37:56.575: E/Web Console(7605): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'processHTML' of undefined at null:1
```

If i remove the `myBrowserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);` declaration, after the loadurl call, everything works correctly.

What i can do to let the code below works?

```
package com.stefano.formfiller;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myBrowser;
    String urlToBrowse = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
    String htmlCode = null;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

          //Browser settings
          WebSettings myBrowserSettings = myBrowser.getSettings();

          //Prevent cache to be used
          myBrowserSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
          myBrowserSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

          //General settings
          myBrowserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          Log.d("Stefano", "JS enabled");

          //FIREFOX user agent
          myBrowserSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0");


          myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
          myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
              public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
              { 

                    WebSettings myBrowserSettings = myBrowser.getSettings();
                    myBrowserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    Log.d("Stefano", "JS enabled");

                    Log.d("Stefano", "OnPageFinished running"); 

              } });


          //Start the delayed HTML code extraction
          delayedStartHtmlExtractor(16000);
          Log.d("Stefano", "DelayedStart HTML Extractor launched");

          //Prepare Javascript to extract the HTML code from the webview
          myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");

          myBrowser.loadUrl(urlToBrowse);
          Log.d("Stefano", "Main URL requested");

          myBrowserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
          Log.d("Stefano", "JS disabled");
    }   


    //Delayed HTML extraction
    public void delayedStartHtmlExtractor(final int delay){
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
        {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {                           


                myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
                Log.d("Stefano", "HTML extraction launched");

                        }
            }, delay);
    }

    //Insert the HTML code in the log information

    class LoadListener{
        public void processHTML(String html)
        {
            Log.d("Stefano", "HTML Extraction in progress...");


            Log.e("HTML CODE",html);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**
I have a doubt: the code instantiate the Javascript interface while the Javascript is enabled (trough myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");); then, i disable the javascript after the URL call, to re-enable the Javascript when the page is fully loaded.

Could it be that when i disable the Javascript with the instantiated Interface, i "cut-off the communication channel" between the Javascipt and the Java code?

Comment: Your comment is not complete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `myBrowser.loadData(...)` after the interface setting, like this

```
myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");
myBrowser.loadData("", "text/html", null);
myBrowser.loadUrl(urlToBrowse);
```

Also since you will disable js by the end of oncreate method there is no need to enable it on its debut :)

Hope this help

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Could you explain why it should work? I've never seen a code which load both loaddata and loadurl. Thanks,

Comment: I saw that, on the documentation of [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface), they say that the added objects will not apear in JavaScript until the page is next (re)loaded.  your code seems logical but weirdly it only work if we add the first loadData!

Comment: okay, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/medhdj/4a6485b07034f4de88dc) to the code that worked for me, it's based on you code

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'm working on it but if i load "https://www.google.it/search?q=dog" as URL, it loads the page with Javascript enabled; so, it's not what i need; i need the page is loaded without Javascript enabled, as i wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should attach the **proper annotation**  `@JavascriptInterface` to the methods that will be called through the [Javascript interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)); in your case:

```
    //..
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {
        Log.d("Stefano", "HTML Extraction in progress...");
        Log.e("HTML CODE",html);
    }
    //..
```

"*Note that injected objects will not appear in JavaScript until the page is loaded*"

**I suppose that loading a page with `setJavaScriptEnabled(false)` will not inject any Javascript object at all**, and this is way you are experiencing this problem.

A possible workaround (untested) could be this:

- always load the page using setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
- load the webpage passing through **http://www.google.com/gwt/n** (will load the page without JS or Flash)
- do your processing

Comment: Thanks for the information. the "@JavascriptInterface" declaration doesn't work with target API level 14 (the one i'm using); i read that is needed over the API level 17. In any case, i tested the "http://www.google.com/gwt/n" manually but it will load the URL without everything (almost complete HTML code too). So, it's a way i can't take.

Comment: @bonnyz You deserve the Nobel prize for the `@JavascriptInterface` tip. I had a perfectly working `API 8` app using this processHTML() method **without** the aforementioned annotation. However, after updating my app's SDK to `API 26`, it ceased working! i.e. processHTML() was never called! Adding `@JavascriptInterface` fixed this! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your LoadListener object, try the following:

```
this.new LoadListener();
```

Comment: I tried this "myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new this.LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");" but it creates an error [Sintax error on token "this", invalid name]

Comment: I changed the above line to this.new LoadListener() instead of new this.LoadListener(). Give it a shot and tell me what happens! Also, is there any reason why LoadListener isn't a static class?

Comment: Nothing changed; same situation. No, there are no special reason for not be static. Can we try something else? What are you thinking about?

Comment: I made some tests; it seems that the JavascriptInterface is not correctly loaded. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In this line: myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML...
Try removing window.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thanks for your time

Comment: I tried and it gives me the following error "E/Web Console(2863): Uncaught ReferenceError: HTMLOUT is not defined at null:1"